# Microphone not working on MiniPC running Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: sound, microphone

*(I'm somewhat new to linux and ubuntu, so be patient with me.)*

I bought a MiniPC recently, a "Beelink SER5 5600H" and installed the latest version of Ubuntu on it. However, yesterday I noticed the system does not recognize my Nierbo microphone. The "Input" section in Settings > Audio displays nothing by default, and "Rear microphone family 17 audio controller" when I do connect my micro, however trying to record something this way gives nothing but static.

If someone could help me out, it'd be very appreaciated :-)

Some notes:

- I'm using a y-splitter to connect the micro to the pc, since it only has a single jack input.
- The micro works just fine when connected to my phone.
- The mic from my wireless headphones gets recognized and works without a problem.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To see if your install of Ubuntu recognizes the audio hardware, please run `sudo lspci -v` (or to filter the output a bit for audio, run `sudo lspci -v | grep -i audio`) and post the results in your question. We're looking for audio devices.